# MYSQL Select Query with SUM()

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
| campaign_id | source_id | clicked | viewed |
----------------------------------------------
| abc         | xxx       | 0       | 0      |  
| abc         | xxx       | 1       | 0      |
| abc         | xxx       | 1       | 1      | 
| abc         | yyy       | 0       | 0      |    
| abc         | yyy       | 1       | 0      |    
| abc         | yyy       | 1       | 1      |    
| abc         | yyy       | 0       | 0      |
```

I need the following output:

```
xxx > Total: 3 // Clicked: 2 // Viewed 1
yyy > Total: 4 // Clicked: 2 // Viewed 1
```

I know that I have to use some sort of SUM() in my query, but I don't know how to differ between those multiple unique values in the source_id (something like foreach, idk).

How can I get such an output which shows stats from all unique source_ids by using only one query?

Comment: I would really like that when someone cast a negative vote comments on the WHY. That's the only way to improve questions.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT source_id, (SUM(clicked)+SUM(viewed)) AS Total
FROM your_table
GROUP BY source_id
```

Comment: Shouldn't I want to group by source_id? Otherwise thanks, I will try this out!

Comment: You should `GROUP BY source_Id`. I also think he wants `SELECT source_id, SUM(clicked) + SUM(viewed) as Total`

Comment: @DonCroce: yes, just a typo. Edited my post :)

Answer (score 6):

Here is your sample data loaded into a table called campaign:

```
CREATE TABLE campaign
(
    campaign_id VARCHAR(10),
    source_id VARCHAR(10),
    clicked int,
    viewed int
);
INSERT INTO campaign VALUES
('abc','xxx',0,0),
('abc','xxx',1,0),
('abc','xxx',1,1),
('abc','yyy',0,0),
('abc','yyy',1,0),
('abc','yyy',1,1),
('abc','yyy',0,0);
SELECT * FROM campaign;
```

Here is what it contains

```
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS campaign;
CREATE TABLE campaign
(
    campaign_id VARCHAR(10),
    source_id VARCHAR(10),
    clicked int,
    viewed int
);
INSERT INTO campaign VALUES
('abc','xxx',0,0),
('abc','xxx',1,0),
('abc','xxx',1,1),
('abc','yyy',0,0),
('abc','yyy',1,0),
('abc','yyy',1,1),
('abc','yyy',0,0);
SELECT * FROM campaign;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE campaign
    -> (
    ->     campaign_id VARCHAR(10),
    ->     source_id VARCHAR(10),
    ->     clicked int,
    ->     viewed int
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO campaign VALUES
    -> ('abc','xxx',0,0),
    -> ('abc','xxx',1,0),
    -> ('abc','xxx',1,1),
    -> ('abc','yyy',0,0),
    -> ('abc','yyy',1,0),
    -> ('abc','yyy',1,1),
    -> ('abc','yyy',0,0);
Query OK, 7 rows affected (0.07 sec)
Records: 7  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM campaign;
+-------------+-----------+---------+--------+
| campaign_id | source_id | clicked | viewed |
+-------------+-----------+---------+--------+
| abc         | xxx       |       0 |      0 |
| abc         | xxx       |       1 |      0 |
| abc         | xxx       |       1 |      1 |
| abc         | yyy       |       0 |      0 |
| abc         | yyy       |       1 |      0 |
| abc         | yyy       |       1 |      1 |
| abc         | yyy       |       0 |      0 |
+-------------+-----------+---------+--------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, here is a good query you need to total and sum by campaign + grand total

```
SELECT
    campaign_id,
    source_id,
    count(source_id) total,
    SUM(clicked) sum_clicked,
    SUM(viewed) sum_viewed
FROM campaign
GROUP BY campaign_id,source_id
WITH ROLLUP;
```

Here is the output:

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->     campaign_id,
    ->     source_id,
    ->     count(source_id) total,
    ->     SUM(clicked) sum_clicked,
    ->     SUM(viewed) sum_viewed
    -> FROM campaign
    -> GROUP BY campaign_id,source_id
    -> WITH ROLLUP;
+-------------+-----------+-------+-------------+------------+
| campaign_id | source_id | total | sum_clicked | sum_viewed |
+-------------+-----------+-------+-------------+------------+
| abc         | xxx       |     3 |           2 |          1 |
| abc         | yyy       |     4 |           2 |          1 |
| abc         | NULL      |     7 |           4 |          2 |
| NULL        | NULL      |     7 |           4 |          2 |
+-------------+-----------+-------+-------------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now dress it up with the CONCAT function

```
SELECT
CONCAT(
    'Campaign ',campaign_id,
    ' Source ',source_id,
    ' > Total: ',
    total,
    ' // Clicked: ',
    sum_clicked
    ,' // Viewed: ',
    sum_viewed) "Campaign Report"
FROM
(SELECT
    campaign_id,
    source_id,
    count(source_id) total,
    SUM(clicked) sum_clicked,
    SUM(viewed) sum_viewed
FROM campaign
GROUP BY
campaign_id,source_id) A;
```

Here is that output

```
mysql> SELECT
    -> CONCAT(
    ->     'Campaign ',campaign_id,
    ->     ' Source ',source_id,
    ->     ' > Total: ',
    ->     total,
    ->     ' // Clicked: ',
    ->     sum_clicked
    ->     ,' // Viewed: ',
    ->     sum_viewed) "Campaign Report"
    -> FROM
    -> (SELECT
    ->     campaign_id,
    ->     source_id,
    ->     count(source_id) total,
    ->     SUM(clicked) sum_clicked,
    ->     SUM(viewed) sum_viewed
    -> FROM campaign
    -> GROUP BY
    -> campaign_id,source_id) A;
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| Campaign Report                                               |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| Campaign abc Source xxx > Total: 3 // Clicked: 2 // Viewed: 1 |
| Campaign abc Source yyy > Total: 4 // Clicked: 2 // Viewed: 1 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT source_id, SUM(clicked + viewed) AS 'Total'
FROM your_table
GROUP BY source_id
```