# rows with the same column value and add their respected int row and sort

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table in my mysql database

`+-------+-----------+------------+
| name  | upvotes   | downvotes  |
+-------+-----------+------------+
| Peter | 5         | 1          |
| Sam   | 2         | 1          |
| Peter | 1         | 4          |
| Peter | 4         | 2          |
| Sam   | 7         | 1          |
+-------+-----------+------------+`

Now, I want to add the upvotes and downvotes of each name. Like this:

`+-------+-----------+------------+
| name  | upvotes   | downvotes  |
+-------+-----------+------------+
| Peter | 10        | 7          | 
| Sam   | 9         | 2          | 
+-------+-----------+------------+`

And I would like to minus the upvotes by downvotes (upvotes - downvotes)

`+-------+-----------+
| name  | total     |
+-------+-----------+
| Peter | 3         |
| Sam   | 7         |
+-------+-----------+`

And lastly I want to echo them like this in a descending order according to the total:

Name      : Sam
Total     : 7
Upvotes   : 11
Downvotes : 4

Name      : Peter
Total     : 3
Upvotes   : 10
Downvotes : 7

I know it's a lot but help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi Peter, just wanted to let you know that people on this site are more inclined to help if they see you've made an effort as well. :) They don't want to feel like they're doing all the work for you. Do you have any code to show from your attempts?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000242/mysql-select-query-with-sum

Comment: Finally I got it ,   ------->    $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT name, SUM(voteup), SUM(votedown)  FROM vote_data GROUP BY name ORDER BY (SUM(voteup)-SUM(votedown)) DESC");   <---------                           Well Thanks Anyway

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MYSQL Select Query with SUM()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000242/mysql-select-query-with-sum)

Comment: Please mark this question as resolved and add your own solution as an answer to help other :)

Comment: @Peter, on Stack Overflow, you don't mark questions as resolved by changing the subject to "[RESOLVED]". You click the green checkmark by the best answer. The site doesn't use comments or the subject line to tell that a question has been answered. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to be more precise

```
$query = "SELECT name, SUM(upvotes) AS upvotes, SUM(downvotes) AS downvotes FROM questions GROUP BY name;";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

You can group by name which gives you the same answer.