# How to multiply two columns and sum it in codeigniter active record?

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

```
ITEM  | PRICE | QTY
lamp  | 5     | 3
lamp  | 7     | 2
pen   | 3     | 15
pen   | 5     | 10
```

I need to query sum of the price of all lamps in codeigniter active record. The result should be 29.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000242/mysql-select-query-with-sum

Comment: I need for codeigniter activerecord query

Comment: build the MYSQL query first, then look at the documentation of CI how to create that query with the [Query Builder Class](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=query%20builder#query-builder-class) (btw.: active records is for version 2.x, if this is a codeigniter-2 question tag it as such, please) and then show what you have tried and where you experienced an error/difficulty. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to multiply the `column names` use `as` to store that data and then use `select_sum` on that value. I've written a query, see if it helps you.

```
$query = $this->db->select_sum('(PRICE * QTY)', 'total')->where('ITEM', 'lamp')->from('your-table-name')->get()->result();
/* 
Produces: 
SELECT SUM((PRICE * QTY)) AS `total` FROM `your-table-name` WHERE `ITEM` = 'lamp'
*/
```

> **OUTPUT**
>
> ```
> Array
> (
>     [0] => stdClass Object
>         (
>             [total] => 29
>         )
>
> )
> ```

Now to get this output-

```
$total = $query[0]->total; // 29
```

Comment: It working great sir, thanks...

`$this->db->select_sum('(PRICE * QTY)', 'total');
$this->db->where('ITEM', 'lamp');
$this->db->from('products');
return $this->db->get()->result();`

Comment: Thanks man! If it helped you, please consider upvoting and/or accepting as an answer. :)

Comment: Done, with this message "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."